# .htaccess throws 403 Forbidden / Zend Framework quickstart project creation (Mac OS X 10.6.5)

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I am trying to get Zend Framework's quickstart tutorial up and running, but i ran into .htaccess issue.  It seems if i remove the .htaccess file, the project runs fine, but if i leave it in there it throws a 403 Forbidden.  The .htaccess is the default file generated by Zend Framework console command.  Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This is under Mac OS X 10.6.5

mod_rewrite is on 
AllowOveride All

Here is my virtual host info

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName zf_cms.local
     DocumentRoot /Users/kjye/Sites/zf_cms/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /Users/kjye/Sites/zf_cms/public>
          Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
          DirectoryIndex index.php
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I fixed it by adding "Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI"  Thanks for viewing.

Comment: Is *mod_rewrite* enabled and *AllowOverride* on (at least) *FileInfo* for the directory?

Comment: I fixed it!!!  I added "Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI" into <Directory>

Comment: I don't think that fixed it, I think you just forgot to restart after changing the default 'Order allow,deny' settings ;)  Also, since you have access to your apache configuration it's more efficient to put the rewrite rules right inside your <directory>.. settings and not use the .htaccess file.

Comment: i tried it again by removing Options _Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI and got the 403 forbidden ... once insert it back into the httpd-vhosts.conf ... it works again.  It has got to be it.

Comment: Very strange - but if it works it works!

Comment: Same problem on Windows, and this unfortunately has no effect...

Comment: @SQLiteNoob its strange, i did not have this issue on Windows.  This was on a Mac

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName zf_cms.local
 DocumentRoot /Users/kjye/Sites/zf_cms/public
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory /Users/kjye/Sites/zf_cms/public>
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

This turns out to work under mac os.  thanks for all the help and comment.

Comment: i get an internal server error with that in mac os 10.7 whenever i access a controller other than my Index controller

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and added

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
```

Can someone shed some clarity on what the actual problem is and what this does to rectify it?