# 403 error on localhost with zend framework 2

Tags: localhost, zend-framework2, http-status-code-403

Ok, so I've been getting the 403 error when trying to load this up - I installed Zend 2 even via youtube guidance of someone fortunate that it's works for out of the box.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111823/403-error-on-zendframework) advice, but that didn't work because `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` wasn't commented out of my `httpd.conf` file.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262270/htaccess-throws-403-forbidden-zend-framework-quickstart-project-creation-mac), but adding `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI` to my `vhosts.conf` file didn't help.

I tried removing the .htaccess file altogether.
I tried commenting out the "XAMPP Security Concept" section of the `httpd-xampp.conf` file.
I tried asking it very nicely, and I tried shouted expletives at it - both strategies proved fruitless.

I'm running Windows 8 and I can't seem to figure out why I am having permission errors. Just to be clear, I am restarted Apache after every change. When I remove the entries from the vhosts.conf file, the 403 is gone, but that causes a 404 in that directory. I've included the relevant code from the `vhosts.conf` file. Thanks for any help!

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName zf2.localhost
        DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Captain/Documents/zf2/public"
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
        <Directory C:/Users/Captain/Documents/zf2/public>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks again.

**UPDATE 1**

The error log is:

```
    [Sun Mar 17 03:35:32.627159 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 5492:tid 1764] [client ::1:50566] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/Captain/Documents/zf2/public/
```

Comment: And the obvious question: What does the error log say?

Comment: @CBroe I've included the line that pops up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it:

Inside  the `httpd.conf` file, change

```
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
```

To:

```
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

That worked for me, and I can access localhost and all directory projects now.