# Permission issue with zf2 routing

Tags: php, zend-framework2, subdomain

In my main domain I have created a sub domain where I have uploaded my files of ZF2 but it it not allowing me to access the home page.

If I type `<submdomainname>.<domainname>.com` it is saying that:

> Forbidden:
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally:

> a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Not really enough info here, that is a standard 403, your webserver logs could tell you more. My guess, assuming Apache, is to check the  [virtual host](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server) for the new sub domain has been added (or a `ServerAlias` to an existing one). Then it's permissions; the [`Require all granted`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458494/403-error-on-localhost-with-zend-framework-2) option comes to mind.

Comment: The error is not related to ZF. Your error is  403 status (forbiden page). You probably need set permission on files because Apache doesn't have privilege to execute the files...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds indeed like a server configuration issue.
Try once to put a simle `index.php` in your folder and see if you can open it:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
echo("Hello world");
```

And add it to your public folder and try to browse to it:

```
http://www.example.com/public/index.php
```

If that doesn't work, then you know at least that it is not related to ZF2.
After you tried this you can come back with more details on your problem.

You should add reading permission to the folder where you host your subdomain.